# How to build Blitz-0.10 library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, blitz++

I need to use blitz++ **0.10** library in vs2012. Unfortunately, I'm new to c++ and don't have enough experience to know how should I build this library.

Till now, I have been using **CMake** to build libraries (e.g., VTK). But in case of blitz, as to why there is no "**CMakeLists.txt**" file, I don't know what should do.

I was wondering If someone could help me in this way (step by step).
(**Win 7**, **64bit**, **VS2012**)

Comment: just open the included visual studio 2010 files, VS2012 will automatically update them to work with VS2012

Comment: Thanks, it worked well. Just a question, I myself can't build this library using CMake and vs2012 (as compiler) in windows 7?

Comment: The VS2010 project "Blitz-Library.sln" does compile the library

Comment: That *.sln can be opened and compiled with VS2012 too in case that wasn't clear (there should be a dialog "Upgrade compiler and libraries" when you open the file with VS2012).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I tried. It's fairly simple. Worked for me

Follow the steps -

1. Download blitz++ from https://github.com/blitzpp/blitz (It will download a zip file)
2. Unzip the file and save it into a folder.
3. Install visual studio 2019(the version i used to check)
4. Install cmake.(ADD it's path to system variable during installation)
5. Open Powershell with admin priviledge(necessary)
6. go to directory where you unzipped the blitz++ (You have to go into the directory where cmakelist.txt file is)
7. Run sequentially

md build

cd build

cmake ..

cmake --build . --config Release

cmake --build . --target install

You will have a blitz folder in program files(x86). include the include lib and include folder in your project properties. Done....