# How do I use blitz++

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, blitz++

I am a beginner in c++. My focus of learning c++ is to do scientific computation. I want to use blitz++ library. I am trying to solve rk4 method but I am not getting the inner workings of the code(I know rk4 algorithm)

```
#include <blitz/array.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace blitz;
using namespace std;

# This will evaluate the slopes. say if dy/dx = y, rhs_eval will return y.  
void rhs_eval(double x, Array<double, 1> y, Array<double, 1>& dydx)
{
    dydx = y;
}

void rk4_fixed(double& x, Array<double, 1>& y, void (*rhs_eval)(double, Array<double, 1>, Array<double, 1>&), double h)
{
    // Array y assumed to be of extent n, where n is no. of coupled equations
    int n = y.extent(0);

    // Declare local arrays
    Array<double, 1> k1(n), k2(n), k3(n), k4(n), f(n), dydx(n);

    // Zeroth intermediate step
    (*rhs_eval) (x, y, dydx);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        k1(j) = h * dydx(j);
        f(j) = y(j) + k1(j) / 2.;
    }

    // First intermediate step
    (*rhs_eval) (x + h / 2., f, dydx);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        k2(j) = h * dydx(j);
        f(j) = y(j) + k2(j) / 2.;
    }

    // Second intermediate step
    (*rhs_eval) (x + h / 2., f, dydx);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        k3(j) = h * dydx(j);
        f(j) = y(j) + k3(j);
    }

    // Third intermediate step
    (*rhs_eval) (x + h, f, dydx);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        k4(j) = h * dydx(j);
    }

    // Actual step
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        y(j) += k1(j) / 6. + k2(j) / 3. + k3(j) / 3. + k4(j) / 6.;
    }
    x += h;
    
    return; # goes back to function. evaluate y at x+h without returning anything
}

int main()
{
    cout << y <<endl; # this will not work. The scope of y is limited to rk4_fixed
}
```

Here are my questions?

1. In rhs_eval x,y are just values. But dydx is pointer. So rhs_eval's output value will be assigned to y. No need to return anything. Am i correct?
2. What does `int n  = y.extent(0)` do? In comment n is saying it's the number of coupled equation. What is the meaning of extent(0). what does extent do? what is that '0'? Is it the size of first element?
3. How do I print the value of 'y'? what is the format? I want to get the value of y from rk4 by calling it from main. then print it.

I compiled blitz++ using MSVS 2019 with cmake using these instruction--
[Instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319869/how-to-build-blitz-0-10-library/71399827#71399827)

I got the code from here- [only the function is given](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/329/lectures/node36.html)

Comment: This will not compile; `this` and `goes` are not valid pre-processor directives.

Comment: *I am a beginner in c++.* --  *I want to use blitz++ library* -- Libraries, API's, frameworks, etc. that are C++ based assume you know the C++ language well-enough to use those libraries and frameworks.  They are *not* designed as teaching tools in learning C++.  C++ is one of the most complex computer languages out there, and using libraries such as blitz++ requires a good, and maybe advanced knowledge of how to use templates, which is not a trivial topic.

Comment: Why are you or the author of the code using a matrix/linear algebra expression template library if you hand-code all the loops over the vector components? Just use std::vector, the code can remain largely unchanged. // Do not use C headers in C++. Do not use pointers if you do not intend to use pointers (like in linked lists or graph structures). Passing arguments by reference is possible in C++ using the reference operator `&`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have done fairly enough coding in 'c'~ upto c99. I am may be at best an intermediate level. I want to get into graduate school to study computational fluid dynamics(A mechanical major). C++ has all the benefits of 'c' and a lot of opensource libraries. 'OpenFoam' is based on 'c++'. So I have to learn how to use these tools effectively and on the go.

Comment: I think it's important to tell anyone asking a blitz question that if they're still in time they should change approach.  The blitz team themselves have recommended against using it.  Check this recent "important notice" in their top level README.md:
https://github.com/blitzpp/blitz/commit/d45a4e210bbb4d4caef983890175a6819c4fb3db#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <blitz/array.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace blitz;
using namespace std;

/* This will evaluate the slopes. say if dy/dx = y, rhs_eval will return y.  */
const double sig = 10; const double rho = 28; const double bet = 8.0 / 3;

void lorenz(double x, Array<double, 1> y, Array<double, 1> &dydx)
{
    /* y vector = x,y,z in components */
    dydx(0) = sig * (y(1) - y(0));
    dydx(1) = rho * y(0) - y(1) - y(0) * y(2);
    dydx(2) = y(0) * y(1) - bet * y(2);
}

void rk4_fixed(double& x, Array<double, 1>& y, void (*rhs_eval)(double, Array<double, 1>, Array<double, 1> &), double h)
{
    int n = y.extent(0);

    Array<double, 1> k1(n), k2(n), k3(n), k4(n), f(n), dydx(n);

    (*rhs_eval) (x, y, dydx);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        k1(j) = h * dydx(j);
        f(j) = y(j) + k1(j) / 2.0;
    }

    (*rhs_eval) (x + h / 2., f, dydx);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        k2(j) = h * dydx(j);
        f(j) = y(j) + k2(j) / 2.;
    }

    (*rhs_eval) (x + h / 2., f, dydx);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        k3(j) = h * dydx(j);
        f(j) = y(j) + k3(j);
    }

    (*rhs_eval) (x + h, f, dydx);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        k4(j) = h * dydx(j);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        y(j) += k1(j) / 6. + k2(j) / 3. + k3(j) / 3. + k4(j) / 6.;
    }
    x += h;
}

int main()
{
    Array<double, 1> y(3);
    y = 1, 1, 1;

    double x = 0, h = 0.05;
    Array<double, 1> dydx(3);
    dydx = 0, 0, 0;

    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        rk4_fixed(x, y, &lorenz, h);
        cout << x << " ,";
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << y(j)<<" ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Another great thing is, it is possible to use blitz++ without any compilation. In Visual Studio 2019, expand {project name} than right click "references" and "Manage NuGet Packages" search for blitz++. download it. No added extra linking or others have to be done.

Comment: Result: [link](https://ibb.co/89m6S2W)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, change also `y` to be passed by reference. Pointer is with `*` or a pointer template, reference is with `&`.
2. Your vector has 1 dimension or extend. In general `Array<T,n>` is a tensor of order `n`, for `n=2` a matrix. `.extend(0)` is the size of the first dimension, with a zero-based index.
3. This is complicated and not well documented. I mean the facilities provided by the Blitz library. You can just manually print the components. For some reason my version produces a memory error if the first print command is commented out.

```
#include <blitz/array.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
//#include <cmath>

using namespace blitz;
using namespace std;

/* This will evaluate the slopes. say if dy/dx = y, rhs_eval will return y.  */
const double sig = 10; const double rho = 28; const double bet = 8.0/3;
void lorenz(double x, Array<double, 1> & y, Array<double, 1> & dydx)
{
    /* y vector = x,y,z in components */
/*
    dydx[0] = sig * (y[1] - y[0]);
    dydx[1] = rho * y[0] - y[1] - y[0] * y[2];
    dydx[2] = y[0] * y[1] - bet * y[2];
*/
    /* use the comma operator */
    dydx = sig * (y[1] - y[0]), rho * y[0] - y[1] - y[0] * y[2], y[0] * y[1] - bet * y[2];

}

void rk4_fixed(double& x, Array<double, 1> & y, void (*rhs_eval)(double, Array<double, 1>&, Array<double, 1>&), double h)
{
    // Array y assumed to be of extent n, where n is no. of coupled equations
    int n = y.extent(0);

    // Declare local arrays
    Array<double, 1> k1(n), k2(n), k3(n), k4(n), f(n), dydx(n);

    // Zeroth intermediate step
    rhs_eval (x, y, dydx);
    k1 = h * dydx; f=y+0.5*k1;
    

    // First intermediate step
    rhs_eval(x + 0.5*h, f, dydx);
    k2 = h * dydx; f =  y+0.5*k2;

    // Second intermediate step
    rhs_eval (x + 0.5*h, f, dydx);
    k3 = h * dydx; f=y+k3;
 
    // Third intermediate step
    rhs_eval (x + h, f, dydx);
    k4 = h * dydx;
 
    // Actual step
    y += k1 / 6. + k2 / 3. + k3 / 3. + k4 / 6.;
    x += h;
    
    return; //# goes back to function. evaluate y at x+h without returning anything
}

int main()
{
    Array<double, 1> y(3);
    y = 1,1,1;
    cout << y << endl;
    double x=0, h = 0.05;
    while(x<20) {
        rk4_fixed(x,y,lorenz,h);
        cout << x;
        for(int k =0; k<3; k++) {
            cout << ", "<< y(k);
        } 
        cout << endl;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why is it throwing an error in visual studio at return rk4_fixed? Exception thrown, hit a breakpoint

Comment: This can depend on the version of the library and how it was compiled. I would recommend to either use std::vector, or the dense matrix type of boost::eigen, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59231161/implementing-modular-runge-kutta-4th for an attempt.

Comment: `@Lutz Lehmann Figured out the problem. since dydx are blitz type array, i can't use indexes as `[ ]` but have to do `( )` in `lorenz` function.  and  `void lorenz(double x, Array<double, 1> y, Array<double, 1> & dydx)` the `&` before y has to be removed.

Also 
`void rk4_fixed(double& x, Array<double, 1> & y, void (*rhs_eval)(double, Array<double, 1>, Array<double, 1>&), double h)` the `&` has to be removed.

during each k1, k2, k3, k4 evaluation an `*` has to be put. such as `*rhs_eval (x, y, dydx);`

Comment: That is quite possible, as said, my version worked, but I used the debian stable package, so there may be differences. In the end, using the comma operator is probably most in line with the blitz philosophy.